# Creating a clean WIM/ESD file out of my current Windows Server 2012 installation

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-installation, dism, wim

Here's my scenario:

We have an old Dell PowerEdge Server with an OEM Windows Server 2012 Foundation license. The machine is working perfectly and there's currently an OS deployment running on it, where it is a domain controller.

We have no use for this machine anymore, so we want to sell it away, but its OEM installation/recovery media has been lost by our previous IT manager. Also, there's no recovery partition in the machine.

Is there a way to make a fresh, clean WIM/ESD/ISO file out of it's current Windows Server 2012 installation? By clean I mean a file that will keep only windows essential files for a new OS installation from scratch, without our data and custom settings.

`DISM /capture-image` wont do the trick as it will add our data and custom settings to the WIM file.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, since I have more important things to care about, I'll proceed with the only solution I've figured so far, that is to manually clean the system as much as possible, demoting it from the DC role, removing all server features and tools, cleaning up all logs, deleting all files and doing a full clean-up with ccleaner, etc, etc, defragging the disk, and run `dism /restorehealth` and `sfc /scannow` a few times to ensure everything is fine, then pack it into a WIM file via `dism /capture-image`. Since the hard drives will be physically destroyed, I don't have worry about doing a secure data destruction before capturing the image.